# struct by reference not changing

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to make a basic linked list in C, I have a struct and an "append" function. However, no matter how many items I add to it, the struct doesn't change at all. I can't find the bug, really.

The struct:

```
typedef struct list {
    int node;
    struct list *next;
} list_t;
```

The append function:

```
void append(list_t *list, int node) {
    if(!list) {
        list = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
        list->node = node;
        list->next = NULL;
    }else {
        list_t *probe = list;
        while(probe->next) probe = probe->next; 
        probe->next = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
        probe = probe->next;
        probe->node = node;
        probe->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

The print function:

```
void lprint(list_t *list) {
    if(!list) {
        printf("empty");
    }else {
        list_t *probe = list;
        do {
            printf("%d ", probe->node);
            probe = probe->next;
        } while(probe);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The main function:

```
void main() {

    list_t *list = NULL;

    int node;
    for(node = 0; node < 5; node++) {
        append(list, node);
        lprint(list);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
empty
empty
empty
empty
empty
```

While it should be:

```
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
```

Any help?

Comment: Duplicate hundreds of times over: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html.

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. The main value of `void main()` is in detecting books written by authors who don't know C as well as they think they do.

Comment: ok thanks, I'm just starting with C. I read the faq but didn't notice how that question was related to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not such thing as "pass by reference" in C. you pass a pointer. by value. If you want to change a pointer, you should pass pointer-to-pointer.

```
void append(list_t **list, int node) {
    assert(list != NULL);
    if(! *list) {
        *list = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
        (*list)->node = node;
        (*list)->next = NULL;
    ...
}
```

Note that this is bad design: you should add a function "create", which will create the list. "append" should do exactly this: appending to an already existing list.

Comment: Thanks, I've just fixed some conceptual issues